# Is there a list of usual meanings to ServiceBase.ExitCode value?

Tags: .net, service, windows-services, exit-code

In the documentation for `ServiceBase.ExitCode`, it simply says that it should be set to "a non-zero value before stopping the service to indicate an error..." Is this number application-specific or is there a list of standard error codes and their meanings somewhere?

Comment: To the downvoter: I would appreciate some feedback as to how to improve the question, if you feel it is lacking in some way.

Comment: It was fumbled in .NET, this should be a Windows error code.  There's another member in the native SERVICE_STATUS structure that gives the service-specific error code.  But isn't exposed in .NET.  In the end this just doesn't matter, the service manager doesn't do anything with it.  Focus on event logging instead.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx